# Get values From ViewModel MutableLiveData and display them on textfields

Tags: java, android, mvvm, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

I am trying to get a hang of the Android Architecture Library and i have been trying to display texts from retrofit via a ViewModel using Mutable LiveData on my Main Activity but i cant seem to do it, i would really appreciate some assistance.

Here is my Model Class

```
public class User {


@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private String name;
@SerializedName("email")
@Expose
private String email;
@SerializedName("phone")
@Expose
private String phone;

public User() {
}

public String getUserName() {
    return name;
}

public void setUserName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getUserEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setUserEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getUserPhone() {
    return phone;
}

public void setUserPhone(String phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}

}
```

My View model

```
public class UserViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

  private NodeAuthService api;
  private SharedPreferences pref;

  private static MutableLiveData<List<User>> userDetails = new 
  MutableLiveData<>();


  private Call<List<User>> call;

  public UserViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
    super(application);
    api = AuthRetrofitClient.getInstance().create(NodeAuthService.class);
  }
  private String email = pref.getString("email", "");

  public void loadUser(){
    call = api.getUser(email);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<User>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<User>> call, Response<List<User>> 
        response) {
            List<User> users =  response.body();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<User>> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("USER",t.getMessage());
        }
    });

  }

  public MutableLiveData<List<User>> getUserDetails(){
    return userDetails;
  }
}
```

Simplified version of my MainActivity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    TextView navName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_name);
    TextView navEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_email);
}
```

Kindly assist

Comment: you need to post value to your live data. i see few problems you have not checked whether the response is successful or not. you don't handle the error case. You should probably move the network call to a repository and get the livedata. you should also observer the livedata in your activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your viewModel

```
public void loadUser(){
    call = api.getUser(email);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<User>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<User>> call, Response<List<User>> 
        response) {
            userDetails.postValue(response.body())
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<User>> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("USER",t.getMessage());
        }
    });

  }
```

And in your Activity observe the changes

```
yourVm.getUserDetails().observe(this, models -> {
                if (models != null) {
                    for(int = 0; i<models.size();i++){
                    /*you will get your list here now iterate through list and get 
                    your email_id here.*/
                   }
                 }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of this

```
List<User> users =  response.body();
```

use this

```
userDetails.postValue(response.body())
```

also, remove static before livedata

inside activity oncreate() init your viewModel instance.
then `viewModel.getUserDEtails().obsever(this, data-> // your stuff);`

Comment: How do i access the individual variables from the observer, the email and name?

Comment: data will of List<User> .
is Your API is returning list of data  or a user object?

if user object only then data will be user type

if List<User> then  iterate thro list and get items